# getenv function not returning expected answer

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm trying to access one of my environement variable, which is `JAVA_HOME`.
To do so, I'm using `getenv()` function, like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char* env = getenv("JAVA_HOME");
    if(env != NULL)
        std::cout << "Environnement : " << env << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "NULL" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tryed `std::getenv("PATH");` which returns me something different from my file `/etc/bash.bashrc` where I put my `JAVA_HOME` variable.

I expected `std::getenv("JAVA_HOME")` to return what I put in my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. Now it returns something different.

How can I get a correct environement variable ? What am I doing wrong ?

I'm under Ubuntu 12.04 with GCC 4.7.2 using C++11 with QtCreator

EDIT : Code

- Include[...] was a shorthand for the includes
- Added NULL handling

EDIT : Progress

- I tryed `extern char **environ` but it doesn't contain the one variable I need ...

EDIT : Partial Solution

There's not way to do such things easily as I found out.
I've set personal environment variables in the IDE to overcome the problem.

Comment: is `#include [...]` actually part of your code?

Comment: I'm pretty certain it should be called `.bashrc` and in your home directory.

Comment: I can't see any *.bashrc file in my home directory ... what should be the full name ?

Comment: Have you verified that the variable is, in fact, set?

Comment: Yes, it is ! I echoed it. It answers well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, except that you should explicitly handle the NULL return value from `getenv()`.

The issue is almost certainly with how your run the code. If you:

1. start a shell;
2. make sure `$JAVA_HOME` is set correctly in that shell (through `bashrc` or whatever other means);
3. run the executable from the shell;

I bet it will work correctly.

Comment: A program that crashes for whatever reason is **NOT** fine.

Comment: You are right ... it works ... why is that so ? I don't understand why I can't get the right information from within my IDE !

Comment: @Xaltar: That's because it inherits the IDE's environment variables. From what you're saying, your IDE doesn't appear to have `JAVA_HOME` set in its environment.

Comment: Then how can I use my own environment variables ? Do you know ?

Comment: I had the same problem... is it solved? I saw the answer is accepted, but still don't know how to make it general (without those settings and running from the shell. This is too inconvenient for people who don't have experience on using shell and environment variables, they expect a simple click to run a program)